# javax.servlet.http package in Apache Karaf 2.3.0

Tags: java, osgi, cxf, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

I've installed **Apache Karaf 2.3.0**. One of my bundles that needs to be installed in it uses  classes from `javax.servlet.http` package. When I try to install the bundle it gives me the error message:

```
karaf@root> ERROR: Bundle com.groupgti.esb.purge [207] Error starting mvn:com.groupgti.esb/esb.purge/1.0.0 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in b
undle com.groupgti.esb.purge [207]: Unable to resolve 207.0: missing requirement [207.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.groupgti.esb.cxf.interceptors) [cau
sed by: Unable to resolve 212.0: missing requirement [212.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet.http)(version>=2.6.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.groupgti.esb.purge [207]: Unable to resolve 207.0: missing requirement [207.0] osgi.wiring.package
; (osgi.wiring.package=com.groupgti.esb.cxf.interceptors) [caused by: Unable to resolve 212.0: missing requirement [212.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=jav
ax.servlet.http)(version>=2.6.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3826)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1868)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1191)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:295)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

`javax.servlet.http` package is exported from: **mvn:org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec/1.1.2** system bundle. The problem is that its version is **2.5** but and my bundle requires at least **2.6.0**. Is there a workaround or something to update the **geronimo-servlet** to the higher version that would be compatible with my bundle? (This is the system bundle).

**Additional information:**

```
CXF Version: 2.7.0
Camel Version 2.10.2
```

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention the important thing. I also updated **CXF** to **2.7.0** version and CXF is the one which is introducing the dependency of Servlet 3.0. This is the graph from dependency tree:

[image]

Maybe will give you some idea on how get around this? The only thing that I could think of is to go back to **CXF 2.6.x**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your bundle really needs something newer than 2.5, you may have problems running it on Karaf 2.3.0.   Karaf 2.3 uses Jetty 7.6.7 which is based on Servlet 2.5.   It doesn't support any of the newer Servlet 3 based API's and such.  You can upgrade the servlet-api bundle and it MAY work, but if your bundle/app uses any of the Servlet 3 functionality, it will likely not work.

Karaf 3 will be upgrading to Jetty 8.1 which does support the Servlet 3 stuff.   Any help testing that and getting that out would be greatly appreciated by the Karaf community.  :-)

Comment: There are a bunch of options.  Likely better to take to the users@cxf.apache.org list.   You could exclude the jetty and servlet-api deps and add deps to the versions you want/need.  You could have the maven-bundle-plugin use a broader range when it generates the MANIFEST, etc....

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use geronimo servlet spec ? Try replacing it with this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: that won't work, since the servlet bundles should be provided by pax-web at this point and 2.3 of Karaf uses Pax-Web 1.1.x which is still bound to Servlet 2.5, Karaf 3.0 will support Pax-Web 2.1 or even 3.0 with full Servlet 3.0 support